# Can't delete child records with trigger on Sequel Pro

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-delete, sequelpro

First I want to say I've never tried using triggers before, and I read a lot of information to do this. What I want to do is delete all records from gallery_assets_meta where its parent_id is equal to gallery_assets.id.

**This was what I tried on sequel pro:**

[image: screenshot]

**My Sql code:**

```
BEGIN
DELETE FROM gallery_assets_meta
    WHERE gallery_assets_meta.parent_id = old.id;
END
```

When I try to delete a record from gallery_assets I get this error:

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Hello. So, what is the problem? what is the question?

Comment: Hello, I edited my question. You can check the error that occurs.

Comment: Hi, seems that sequel pro checks for the total number of records affected and throws this error for some reason.

Comment: Would you consider not using the trigger and calling the command "DELETE FROM gallery_assets_meta
    WHERE gallery_assets_meta.parent_id = old.id;" before the deletion of the row in "gallery_assets"?

Comment: Yes, and the result is the same. Except when I do it AFTER it deletes the field from gallery_assets but not the correspondent childs of gallery_assets_meta